# Issue with the margin in a thesis

Tags: margins, thesis

I'm currently working on my thesis, and I'm encountering an issue with the margin. The margin on both sides is not consistent, and I'd like to adjust it to be the same on both sides and appear narrower than it does in the picture. Any guidance or suggestions on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

```tex
\documentclass[
11pt, 
twoside, 
english, 
singlespacing, 
headsepline,
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `oneside` instead of `twoside`.  You might also need to use geometry, but `twoside` is deliberately assymetrical.